# Importing existing logic app template to a Visual Studio Azure Resource Group Project

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Currently i have 4 logic apps created using the azure portal.
I am trying to import these to an Azure Resource Group Project in Visual Studio 2015.

The 4 logic apps and their api connections are located in one resource group in azure. We are currently working on creating a more manageable deployment situation.

Is there any way of doing this directly, or do i actually have to recreate the logic apps in my VS project, in order to have a proper way of deploying them to the different environments (dev, test, production)?

I've tried having a look at the Get-LogicAppTemplate powershell module, without having any luck.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried exporting Resource Group template from Azure portal. You can export the template by opening the Resource Group -> Automation script -> Download.

Once you have your template downloaded, create a new Azure Resource Group project in Visual Studio with empty template.
You can now add the downloaded template to your solution and make modifications as per your requirements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not work for larger resource groups (approaching 1000 resources per), and the inter-relationships get shattered with most slice downloads and virtually impossible to repair